# TCPDF dejavusans font problem - unable to open a file with text

Tags: php, fonts, cakephp-3.0, tcpdf

I am working in my [CakePHP 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html) project and I am using [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) (https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf) library which is working fine. However when I am using below font, it is opening the PDF file but texts not showing at all. Here is the font which I am using.

```
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 8, '', true);
```

And here is how my file is opening.

[image]

But if I comment the above line, its working absolutely fine.

[image]

I have also tried to use below code to make it work.

```
$pdf->addFont('dejavusans', 'B', 'dejavusansb.php');
$pdf->addFont('dejavusans', 'I', 'dejavusansi.php');
$pdf->addFont('dejavusans', '',  'dejavusans.php');
$pdf->setFont('dejavusans', '', 9);
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 9,'', true);
```

But none of the above options working for me. I have also checked whether my fonts are exists or not and it seems its there but may be its corrupted I am not sure. Here are my fonts are situated in my project directory.

[image]

I have also checked my `error.log` file and its giving me below  errors saying.

> Warning: Warning (2): gzuncompress() [http://php.net/function.gzuncompress'>function.gzuncompress]: data error in [/var/www/html/ouvar-web-app/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php, line 8799]
>
> Warning: Warning (2): unpack() [http://php.net/function.unpack'>function.unpack]: Type N: not enough input, need 4, have 0 in [/var/www/html/ouvar-web-app/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_static.php, line 1974]
>
> Warning: Warning (2): gzuncompress() [http://php.net/function.gzuncompress'>function.gzuncompress]: data error in [/var/www/html/ouvar-web-app/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php, line 8799]
>
> Warning: Warning (2): unpack() [http://php.net/function.unpack'>function.unpack]: Type N: not enough input, need 4, have 0 in [/var/www/html/ouvar-web-app/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_static.php, line 1974]

I have already set my debug mode to false. Yet its giving me above errors.

```
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', false), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

I have checked to solve above errors but its saying me to modify inside my library inside my font file which I guess its not feasible to do so.

Can someone guide me how can I solve this error.

**Update**: I have dynamic data but even if I put below single line of code to open my PDF file, yet its not working.

```
$get_data = '<h1>test</h1>';
```

If I comment the `dejavusans` font, then its working fine.

**Update**: I have also downloaded TDPDF library and copied and replaced whole `fonts` folder to my project. Yet its not working.

I have also changed `SetFont` code from `$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 8, '', true);` to `$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);`. Yet its not working.

**Update**: Now, I have even copied and replaced my whole `tcpdf` library folder which includes files and folders like `config` , `examples`, `include` etc. Yet its not working. Giving me same errors like before.

Comment: From the error message you've included, it's trying to uncompress something, and failing. So, most likely that one of the `.z` files is incorrect. Maybe corrupted, maybe you renamed something to that name instead of compressing it,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I have mentioned in my *UPDATE* I downloaded `fonts` folder from original library which is working fine with these fonts and copied and replaced with them as a whole folder. Yet its not working.